# How to evaluate this contour integral: $ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{ \frac{a \cos(x) + x \sin(x)}{ x^2 + a^ 2} } dx $

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

Need to evaluate this using contour integration:

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{ \frac{a \cos(x) + x \sin(x)}{ x^2 + a^ 2} } dx $$

I usually proceed by considering a semicircular region of radius R, and evaluate this as the difference between integral on closed semicircle (I1) and the integral on the semicircular arc (I2). Finally I take limit as R tends to infinity.

However here i am stuck calculating I2. Any leads will be appreciated.

Edit: I computed I1 using Cauchy formula. I need help with I2 only.

Edit 2: I was making a mistake in taking bound too, I2 vanishes. 
$$ | I2 | < |e^{ix}| \frac{a + R} {R^2 - a^2} \times {\pi R} < e^{-R} \frac{a + R} {R^2 - a^2} \times {\pi R}. $$

The above vanishes as $ R \to \infty $.

Comment: Usually the integral I2 vanishes, as R tends to infinity. I can't seem to do that here.

Comment: Intuitively, there is some sort of cancellation occurring along the semicircle. This kind of case can be tackled with [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma).

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art, yes, I usually use that. But here it results in $\pi$ as the upper bound. Are you able to show that it vanishes using Jordan's lemma?

Comment: It most certainly does not give $\pi$ as an upper bound. In fact, you should get $\pi(a+R)/(R^2+a^2)$ as an upper bound, assuming $a>0$.

Comment: Are you sure you're not missing an $R$? $ I = (\pi R \frac{(a + R)} {R^2 - a^2})$. No?

Comment: No. Did you read the wikipedia page I linked? (The denominator ought to be $R^2-a^2$, so you are correct on that.)

Comment: Okay, i confused this with another theorem. This helps, thank you.

Comment: I found the mistake in the my approach. Added as edit. Thank you.

Comment: That inequality is most definitely not true, as $|e^{iz}|=1$ when $z$ is real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a>0$ take the real part of $$\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{\partial ([-R,R] + i [0,R])}  \frac{a e^{ix} - ix e^{ix}}{ x^2 + a^ 2} dx = 2i \pi Res(\frac{a e^{ix} - ix e^{ix}}{ x^2 + a^ 2} ,ia)$$

The obtained expression will stay true for $\Re(a) > 0$ by analytic continuation.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with that notation of writing domain. Is it $ -R < x < R, 0 < y < R$? Also, I don't understand how this will give us I2.

Comment: The integral over the rectangle which is the boundary of $[-R,R] +i [0,R]$

Comment: Okay, I got that. So we computed the integral along the rectangular boundary. How do I get to I2 or I from here?

Comment: When $R \to \infty$ only one side of the rectangle is non-zero

Comment: Got it, thank you so much. Any hints on when to take a rectangle vs semicircle vs something else?

Comment: It doesn't change anything here. The point is that $\cos(x)$ doesn't decay as $\Im(x) \to \infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97010/discussion-between-utkarsh-kumar-and-reuns).

Comment: I found the mistake in my approach. I added it as edit.

Comment: No... You have absolutely no reason to think that your $I_2$ vanishes, again $\cos(x)$ and ${ \frac{a \cos(x) + x \sin(x)}{ x^2 + a^ 2} }$ grow very fast as $\Im(x) \to \infty$

Comment: I think you're making a mistake in the sign. As $\Im(x) \to \infty, 2 cos(x) = e^{-Im(x)} (e^{i \Re(x)} + e^{- i\Re(x)}) \to 0$. (Integrals over 3 sides of your rectangle vanish, it makes sense that integral over semi circular arc, I2, will vanish. No?)

Comment: No.. $2\cos(x) = e^{ix} + e^{-ix}$ and $e^{-ix}$ grows very fast as $\Im(x) \to + \infty$